# Undo git reset HEAD~3

Tags: git, git-reset

I was stepped down from my git repo into 3 step below by using,

```
git reset HEAD~3
```

but after that i didnt find my previous changes. so how do i undo this `reset HEAD~3`

Comment: A time machine.

Comment: Did you have unstaged changes at the time? If not, you should be able to get back to where you are using `git reflog`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git reset HEAD@{1}  # where you want to HEAD
```